# How do you create headers/footers in a PDF file using iText (itext-1.4.5.jar) in Jython?

Tags: pdf, itext, jython

I am trying to add headers and footers to a PDF file using iText in Jython. The itext version is the one found in itext-1.4.5.jar. I cannot change or update the itext version. I can create a PDF but I need the headers/footers as well. I can't find any examples in Jython or Python for adding headers/footers.

Any help greatly appreciated. 
This is what I have at the moment to create a simple PDF:

```
import sys

from java.io import FileOutputStream

try:
    from com.lowagie.text.pdf import PdfReader
    from com.lowagie.text.pdf import PdfWriter
    from com.lowagie.text import Document
    from com.lowagie.text import Paragraph
    from com.lowagie.text.pdf import PdfTable

    FileNameOut = "C:\\TEMP\\TEST.PDF"

    document = Document()
    PDFOut = FileOutputStream(FileNameOut)
    pdfW = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, PDFOut)

    document.open()
    newPara = Paragraph("Hello")
    document.add(newPara)
    document.close()

except:
    print("* Error: %s %s" % (sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1]))
    print("* Locals: %s" % (str(locals())))

finally:
    print("Finished")
```

Comment: Abandon all hope when you see my name in your package names. iText 1.4.5 dates from 2006. Do not expect anyone, not even the original developer (that's me), to support software that is 10 years old.

Comment: If you were using iText 5.5.9 or iText 7.0.0, I would find it an interesting exercise to try out some Jython. Never used it, limited experience with Python, but out of sheer curiosity I would give it a shot. With iText 1.4.5 I'm not even going to bother, sorry.

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to give a response.